# "Search on" versus "search for"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Let's say I'm doing some research on something on Google. Do I say I'm *searching on* or *searching for* something on Google?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's *search for*. In fact, this is the first time I see *search on* at all. And indeed, as a quick-and-dirty check, the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](http://www.americancorpus.org/) has a measly 217 cites for "search on" (as opposed to 10.220 for "search for"). The British National Corpus has 39 and 2028 cites, respectively.

Comment: I think "search on" is perfectly normal usage where the particular search engine (or search facility within an application) is not a variable to be considered. In such cases, *"search on [some search text]"* might sound a little "technical" compared to *"search for"*, but it doesn't seem at all "odd" to me. Mind you, I don't have a problem with *"search with [some text]"* in that context either, so I'm probably a bit more liberal than most.

Answer (score 2):

You're searching *for* something on Google, or you're *googling* something.

Answer (score 1):

When regarding search in general, it is not uncommon to 'search on (field or criteria) to find  (desired result)'

> Search on the 'Sent On' field to find email that was sent last March.